# jQuery : Changing class of button with AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am building up a Like/Unlike system, I have a button what has a class like, if i click it data is inserted in the database, and the class is changed to unlike.

And unlike suppose to pull another ajax call what removes the actual like but its not working, when the class changed it preforms what like class suppose to do, and it only works if i refresh the page.

php code

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
<?php
    $like = '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-small like" data-like="'.$user->id.'">
        <i class="icon-thumbs-up icon-white"></i> Like
    </button>';  
    foreach ($user->likes as $likes) {
        if($likes['liked_by'] == Session::get('sentry_user')) {
          $like = '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-small unlike" data-like="'.$user->id.'">
            <i class="icon-thumbs-down icon-white"></i> Unlike
            </button>'; 
            break 1;
         }
    }
    echo $like; 
 ?>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('button.like').bind('click', function(){
    var likeId = $(this).data('like');
    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + 'profile/like',
        type: "post",
        data: {user_id: likeId},
        dataType: "json",
        context: this,
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $(this).addClass('disabled');
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data.status == "like") {
                $(this).removeClass('like')
                .addClass('unlike')
                .append()
                .html('<i class="icon-thumbs-down icon-white"></i> Unlike');
            }
        },
        complete: function()
        {
            $(this).removeClass('disabled');
        }
    });

});

$('button.unlike').bind('click', function(){
    var likeId = $(this).data('like');
    alert('you are about to unlike');


})
```

just made the unlike alert for an example to test it befoe I make the ajax call with it.

So cloud someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've done something similar on my app, i used this logic:

html:

```
<a class="like" onclick="like($(this))"></a>
```

js:

```
    function like(_element){

    if($(_element).hasClass('unlike')){

$.ajax(); //do unlike
    $(_element).removeClass('unlike'); // this goes inside the success:function(){} of the ajax call

}else{

     $.ajax(); //do like    
     $(_element).addClass('unlike'); // this goes inside the success:function(){} of the ajax call

}

    }
```

also you can refactoring this example for using just 1 ajax call, you will have less code

Comment: thanks for the help, dunno why i didnt think of this first, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `$(selector).toggleClass();` like so:

jQuery:

```
$('button.like,button.unlike').on('click',function(){
    $.ajax(
        ...
        $(this).toggleClass('like unlike');
    );
})
```

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oluzik/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

you may use a library like http://phery-php-ajax.net that makes you able to keep your code DRY and you can reuse the code without having to rebind the click event:
This will work for all buttons that are added through ajax and can be reused everywhere

`data-remote` is the name of the remote function, in this case, action. It works using event delegation, so no need to manually bind the click event to the buttons

```php
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
<?php
$like = '<button data-remote="action" class="btn btn-primary btn-small like" data-args="'.Phery::args(array('id' => $user->id, 'perform' => 'like')).'">
    <i class="icon-thumbs-up icon-white"></i> Like
</button>';  
    foreach ($user->likes as $likes) {
       if($likes['liked_by'] == Session::get('sentry_user')) {
         $like = '<button data-remote="action" class="btn btn-primary btn-small unlike" data-args="'.Phery::args(array('id' => $user->id, 'perform' => 'unlike')).'">
         <i class="icon-thumbs-down icon-white"></i> Unlike
         </button>'; 
         break 1;
      }
    }
    echo $like; 
  ?>
</div>
```

Your like/unlike callback

```php
// in your profile/like

function action($data){
  $r = new PheryResponse;
  // $data['id'] got the ID of the like
  if ($data['perform'] === 'like'){
    $r
    ->this()
    ->removeClass('like')
    ->addClass('unlike')
    ->phery('set_args', array('id' => $data['id'], 'perform' => 'unlike'))
    ->html('<i class="icon-thumbs-down icon-white"></i> Unlike'); // exchange the data
  } elseif ($data['perform'] === 'unlike'){
    $r
    ->this()
    ->removeClass('unlike')
    ->addClass('like')
    ->phery('set_args', array('id' => $data['id'], 'perform' => 'like'))
    ->html('<i class="icon-thumbs-up icon-white"></i> Like'); // exchange the data
  }
  return $r;
}

Phery::instance()->set(array(
  'action' => 'action'
))->process();
```