# Using AJAX to create a like and delike function with php and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

First of all, i have searched, and I have asked this question once before:
[Creating a Like function php mysql ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769110/creating-a-like-function-php-mysql-ajax)

The DB problem in that thread was solved. And i followed the instructions to create a second thred, for the AJAX problem.

I found this [jQuery : Changing class of button with AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469947/jquery-changing-class-of-button-with-ajax-call), and it looks simpel and very nice. And i have also followed this http://pluscss.com/tutorials/ajax-like-script-using-php-mysql-jquery tutorial. But I'm having problems combine them.

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. count the current amount of likes
2. check if the user have liked it before
3. give the user the option to like (or delike if previously liked)

with ajax and like.php as a respons page (or whatever)

Im trying to create a function that will return the current amount of likes (I'm no good at creating functions, sorry bout that)

```
function like($post_id,$comment_id)
{
$count = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as TOTAL_COMMENT_LIKES FROM `comments_likes` 
WHERE comment_id_fk='".$comment_id."'");
if $row_array=$count->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); < 0
then echo "be the first to like"
else
check if user already have liked it
give option to delike

if not have liked
then give option to like

return $TOTAL_COMMENT_LIKES or $TOTAL_POST_LIKE
}
```

I have two tables, one for the liked posts and one for liked comments

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post_likes` (
  `like_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id_fk` INT(11),
  `uid_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `ip` varchar(39) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
FOREIGN KEY (post_id_fk) REFERENCES posts(post_id),
FOREIGN KEY (uid_fk) REFERENCES users(user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comment_likes` (
  `like_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_id_fk` INT(11),
  `uid_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `ip` varchar(39) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
FOREIGN KEY (comment_id_fk) REFERENCES comments(comment_id),
FOREIGN KEY (uid_fk) REFERENCES users(user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

And to top it of with AJAX:

```
   function like(_element){

    if($(_element).hasClass('unlike')){

$.ajax(); //do unlike
    $(_element).removeClass('unlike'); // this goes inside the success:function(){} of the ajax call

}else{

     $.ajax(); //do like    
     $(_element).addClass('unlike'); // this goes inside the success:function(){} of the ajax call

}

    }
```

All help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Need to be more specific about what problems you have, and any errors that are being encountered. Suggest you break this into smaller parts. Start with html and event handling since that code is very incomplete. Then get ajax working , then last step integrate db

Comment: What's the problem? Are you asking us to do the function for you?

Comment: The variable `$mysqli` is not accessible in your function because you didn't pass it in as a parameter. You need to learn about variable scope; read the PHP manual. (Not to mention most of your function is also pseudo-code...)